# Recursive function in C

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void recursie(int);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  recursie(3);
}

void recursie(int a){
  if(a==0){return;}
    recursie(a-1);
    printf("%d",a);
    recursie(a-1);
}
```

The output is : 1213121. Can someone explain me how i get to this output ?

Comment: Try replacing the `"%d"` format string with `"%d\n"` and use a debugger (like `gdb`); you could also add more `printf`. But I don't understand what is surprising you.

Comment: What did you expect, and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
recursie(3)
  -calls recursie(2)
   - calls recursie(1)
     -calls recursie(0) -> void
     -prints 1
     -calls recursie(0) -> void
   -prints 2
   -calls recursie 1
      -calls recursie 0 -> void
      -prints 1
      -calls recursie 0 -> void
  -prints 3
  -calls recursie(2)
   - calls recursie(1)
     -calls recursie(0) -> void
     -prints 1
     -calls recursie(0) -> void
   -prints 2
   -callse recurse 1
      -calls recusie 0 -> void
      -prints 1
      -calls recursie 0 -> void
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the order in which recursion occurs vis a vis that of the `prinf()`. If you work out the order of calls, ignore `recursie(0)` because it is a no-op (does nothing) and flatten them to a simple list of statements what you get is:

```
recursie(3-1);
printf("%d", 3);
recursie(3-1);
```

Which leads to:

```
recursie(2-1);
printf("%d", 2);
recursie(2-1);
printf(3);
recursie(2-1);
printf("%d", 2);
recursie(2-1);
```

Which in turn works out as:

```
printf("%d", 1);
printf("%d", 2);
printf("%d", 1);
printf("%d", 3);
printf("%d", 1);
printf("%d", 2);
printf("%d", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of calling it on `n` is the string of `n` surrounded by two copies of the output of calling it on `n-1`, except that the output of calling it on `0` is nothing. This means the output of calling it on `1` is `"1"`, so the output of calling it on `2` is `"121"` (`"2"` surrounded by copies of `"1"`), and the output of calling it on `3` is `"1213121"` (`"3"` surrounded by two copies of `"121"`).

Answer (score 0):

When new concepts like these seem confusing, grab a piece of notebook paper and graph everything out. You'll see that the reason that the number 3 is in the center is that you're running two recursive functions on either side of its printing, leaving an equal padding for 3 to be in the center. The next is that 2 is left in the center of its padding (1's). This is for the same reason that 3 is in the center. 1 is on either sides and there are no 0s because you said `if 0, stop`.

Was there a *specific* result you were looking for that wasn't achieved?